# HTML5 grid sizing

Tags: html, svg

I am creating an HTML5 grid for a website. The grid looks the way I would like it to, however in each "big" square, there are 10 smaller squares. I need there to be only 5 squares in each "big" square. I am not proficient in HTML5 and am not sure how to even word the question, hopefully someone understands what I am trying to do here.

HERE is the site: http://www.webexplosive.com/sms_test/piermap.html

and HERE is my grid code:

```
<div style="width: 902px; height: 602px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 86px;">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
   <pattern id="minorGrid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="#FF4444" stroke-width="0.5"/>
   </pattern>
   <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#minorGrid)"/>
     <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"/>
   </pattern>
</defs>

      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cBXER/

```
<div style="width: 902px; height: 602px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 86px;">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="minorGrid" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path d="M 20 0 L 0 0 0 20" fill="none" stroke="#FF4444" stroke-width="0.5"/>
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#minorGrid)"/>
                <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"/>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

You need to change your minor grid width, height and path d values to 20 because 20 is one-fifth of 100.

Comment: Hell yeah, thanks a lot, Ben! You answered my question, as well as a couple others!